# Market Order Filler for A Single Commodity Market and No Extra Users

Tags: c++

This is my example program for a single commodity market. It's meant to demonstrate filling of orders for a single product. Right now it doesn't deal with anything more than updating quantities, I plan to implement remaining money and money received. I would like feedback about my use of typedefs, and any way to better write this. Right now, I feel like I'm violating DRY.

```
/**\file market_test.cpp
 * \author Henry Schmale
 * \date May 27, 2018
 *
 * A simple program meant to demo order filling through a command line program
 */

#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>


typedef int Price;

class Market {
    private:
        struct Listing {
            static size_t NEXT_ID;

            size_t  id;
            size_t  initialQuantity;
            size_t  remainingQuantity;
            Price   price;

            Listing();
            Listing(Price price, size_t quantity);

            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,
                    const Listing& l) {
                stream << "Listing(id=" << l.id << "\tprice=" << l.price << "\tq="
                    << l.remainingQuantity << "/" << l.initialQuantity 
                    << ")" << std::endl;
                return stream;
            }

        };

        // buy offers with a higher price get processed first
        struct CompareBuying {
            bool operator() (const Listing& lhs, const Listing& rhs) const {
                return lhs.price < rhs.price;
            }
        };

        // sell offers with a lower price get processed first
        struct CompareSelling {
            bool operator() (const Listing& lhs, const Listing& rhs) const {
                return lhs.price > rhs.price;
            } 
        };

        typedef std::vector<Listing> ul_stor;

        typedef std::priority_queue<Listing,ul_stor,CompareBuying> BuyQueue;
        typedef std::priority_queue<Listing,ul_stor,CompareSelling> SellQueue;

        BuyQueue buyOffers;
        SellQueue sellOffers;

        void fillOrders();

    public:
        Market();
        bool makeSellOffer(int price, size_t quantity);
        bool makeBuyOffer(int price, size_t quantity);
        void listOffers();
        void listBuying();
        void listSelling();
};

int main() {
    std::string line;
    Market m;

    std::cout <<    
        "Market Fill Engine Test\n\n"
        "A demonstration of a market order filler for a single\n"
        "commodity market \n" 
        "Commands to buy and sell are like so:\n\n"
        "      {buy,sell} <price:int -gt 0> <quantity: unsigned>\n\n\n"
        "To List Open Orders:\n\n"
        "       list\n"
        << std::endl;

    while(getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::string verb;
        Price p; size_t q;


        std::stringstream sstr(line);

        sstr >> verb >> p >> q;

        if(verb == "buy") {
            m.makeBuyOffer(p, q);
        } else if (verb == "sell") {
            m.makeSellOffer(p, q); 
        } else if (verb == "list") {
            m.listOffers();
        }
    }


    return 0;
}


Market::Market() {}

size_t Market::Listing::NEXT_ID = 0;


Market::Listing::Listing(Price p, size_t q) 
    : price(p), initialQuantity(q), remainingQuantity(q), id(NEXT_ID++) {}


    bool Market::makeSellOffer(int p, size_t q) {
        assert(p > 0);

        Listing l(p, q);

        sellOffers.push(l);

        fillOrders();
        return false;
    }

bool Market::makeBuyOffer(int p, size_t q) {
    assert(p > 0);

    Listing l(p, q);

    buyOffers.push(l);

    fillOrders();
    return false;
}

void Market::fillOrders() {
    for(;;) {
        if (!(buyOffers.size() && sellOffers.size()))
            return;

        // Grab the current offers
        Listing buying = buyOffers.top();
        Listing selling = sellOffers.top();
        buyOffers.pop();
        sellOffers.pop();

        if (buying.price >= selling.price) {
            if (buying.remainingQuantity > selling.remainingQuantity) {
                buying.remainingQuantity -= selling.remainingQuantity;
                selling.remainingQuantity = 0;
            } else {
                selling.remainingQuantity -= buying.remainingQuantity;
                buying.remainingQuantity = 0;
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

        // Return the offers if not completely filled
        if (buying.remainingQuantity > 0)
            buyOffers.push(buying);
        if (selling.remainingQuantity > 0)
            sellOffers.push(selling);
    }
}

void Market::listOffers() {
    listBuying();
    listSelling();
}

void Market::listBuying() {
    BuyQueue copy (buyOffers);
    while(!copy.empty()) {
        Listing l = copy.top();
        copy.pop();
        std::cout << "buy\t" << l;
    }    
}

void Market::listSelling() { 
    SellQueue copy (sellOffers);
    while(!copy.empty()) {
        Listing l = copy.top();
        copy.pop();
        std::cout << "sell\t" << l;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- I highly doubt you need to flush the stream after your introduction text in `main`.
- As there are no other control paths returning values the `return 0` at the end of `main` is not necessary and can be omitted.
- I believe you're missing `<cstddef>` for `size_t` and you're also missing `<vector>`.
- Your error checking via `assert` is questionable. Consider *someone* compiling this with `-DNDEBUG` and now all your `assert`s are gone.
- Variable names could use some work. `p`, `q`and `ul_stor` are not the most telling names I've ever encountered.
- Regarding your `typedef`s you might want to consider using the [`type_alias`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead.
- Don't declare more than one variable per line.
- Constructor member initializer lists become a lot more readable if you format them like this:

  ```
  Market::Listing::Listing(Price p, size_t q)
      : price(p)
      , initialQuantity(q)
      , remainingQuantity(q)
      , id(NEXT_ID++) 
      {}
  ```
- [Prefer prefix over postfix](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59880/avoid-postfix-increment-operator)
- Your `list*` functions look *interesting*. Copying just so you can display the queue is probably not the best idea. Perhaps a different data structure might be more fitting for this project.

Comment: I wish that there was another container I could use, but I want the log(n) push pop, with highest value at the top. I could use std::heapify, but that's O(N). I don't exactly want to create my own container just to get those features.